# Set attribute of the object in array to true but others to false

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im looking for right way to write this, I have an array of students and every student has an attribute isSelected which is set to true or false, when the button is clicked, student is selected and this is the method:
(I want others students attributes to be set to false)

```
selectStudent(id) {
        this.students[id].isSelected = true
        this.selectedStudent = this.students[id]

        let studentsFalse = this.students.filter(studentId => studentId != this.students[id])
        for (let i= 0; i < studentsFalse.length; i++) {
            studentsFalse[i].isSelected = false
        }
    },
```

Comment: If the objective is to ensure only 1 student is selected at any given time, rather than iterate through the array & set all other students to `false`, do you want to consider something like setting a `selectedIndex` to the index of the one student that is selected. Then, your `selectedStudent` will be `this.students[selectedIndex]`

Comment: @Smna I just added an answer. Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the array and set the values to true or false depending on whether the item is at the correct index.

```js
selectStudent(id) {
        this.selectedStudent = this.students[id]

        for (let i= 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
            this.students[i].isSelected = i === id;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

With generic for you may do this, all students will have their property modified, just check if the student's `key` matches the id parameter.

```js
selectStudent(id) {
    this.selectedStudent = this.students[id];

    for (let key=0; key<this.students.length; key++) {
        this.students[key].isSelected = key === id;
    }
}
```

To test here:

```js
const object = {
    students: [
        {
            name: "Fernanda",
            isSelected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Paula",
            isSelected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Gabriel",
            isSelected: false
        }
    ],

    selectedStudent: null,

    selectStudent(id) {
        this.selectedStudent = this.students[id];

        for (let key=0; key<this.students.length; key++) {
            this.students[key].isSelected = key === id;
        }
    }
}

object.selectStudent(1);
console.log(`Selected student: ${object.selectedStudent.name}`);
object.selectStudent(2);
console.log(`New selected student: ${object.selectedStudent.name}`);
console.log(object.students);
```

Comment: Arrays aren't supposed to be iterated with for..in.

Comment: fixed, i thought it was a object not array

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      students: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Student 1',
        isSelected: false
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Student 2',
        isSelected: false
      }],
      studentSelected: false
  },
  methods: {
    selectStudent(event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.students.forEach((student) => {
            student.isSelected = parseInt(event.target.value) === parseInt(student.id)
        })
      }
      console.log('updated students list : ', this.students)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="student in students" :key="student.id">
        <input type="checkbox" :value="student.id" v-model="student.isSelected" id="student.id" @click="selectStudent">
        {{student.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```